# selenium firefox custom download location seems to be ignored

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have tried everything suggested in SO threads for this so I must be doing something else wrong. So I apologize if this seems like another repeat of many similar threads.

I'm trying to set a custom download location for firefox in my python selenium project with:

```
options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", 'C:\\temp')
```

However the setting seems to be ignored, with downloads only going to the default windows download folder.

```py
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument("-safe-mode")
options.set_preference("extensions.enabledScopes", 0)
print("todo: troubleshoot why custom download dir isnt being utilized")
options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", 'C:\\temp')
```

I'm using:

```
selenium version: 4.10.0
Firefox version: 114.0.1
FirefoxDriver version: 0.33.0
```

I've tried all combinations of the folder value I can think of, with single and double , and double or single quotes, and an r at the front. I've also tried when the other option arguments were disabled. None of my attempts have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working setup for Firefox with custom download folder (accounting for situations where you are trying to download .PDF files):

```
firefox_options = Firefox_Options()
firefox_options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
firefox_options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\temp")
firefox_options.set_preference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", True)
firefox_options.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)

firefox_options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf")
```

Selenium documentation can be found [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/).

Comment: Thanks @Barry, yours was the first answer that appeared which I tried - and this worked. Brilliant :)

Answer (score 0):

With your chosen folder (`C:\\temp`), these are the options to use for all scenarios:

```py
options = Firefox_Options()
options.set_preference("browser.download.panel.shown", False)
options.set_preference("browser.download.animateNotifications", False)
options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\temp")
options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
options.set_preference(
    "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
    (
        "application/pdf, application/zip, application/octet-stream, "
        "text/csv, text/xml, application/xml, text/plain, "
        "text/octet-stream, application/x-gzip, application/x-tar "
        "application/"
        "vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, Barry's solution was the first that appeared which I tried - which worked - however this looks interesting which I'll also be exploring!